# DELETE in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete, mismatch

I'm trying to use the delete command in Access using the shown specifications, but Access keeps saying "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." Does anyone know what to do?

```
DELETE ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (((ORDERS.OrderDate)='2008-01-24') AND ((ORDERS.CustomerID)="C0003"));
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying a query to make sure you are actually selecting something?

Comment: @TKEyi60 It looks like it's selecting something but then it yells at me.

Comment: What does it yell at you?

Comment: @AndrewGibson "Data mismatch in criteria expression" :p

Comment: Use the Debug.Print and print out a selection from your record set.  Also add break points in the VBA with F8 to maybe step through and view the immediate window.

Comment: Or build the query in Design View, test it from there, and check the SQL View text. (You may be doing this already..)

Comment: The query is incorrect. What does it mean by `DELETE Column1, Column2`? If you intend to delete the entire row, use `DELETE *` Please refer http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/delete-statement-HA001231444.aspx

Comment: @shahkalpesh beat me to it! It is distracting because it is accepted with the column names when you design the query.

Comment: @AndrewGibson I actually didn't even write it that way, Access made it like that. It's still giving me the same error. I tried building it in Design View but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: @shahkalpesh See above ^

Comment: @RachelleBennington: Use SQL view instead of Design view and type in the query as `DELETE * FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDERS.OrderDate = #1/24/2008# AND ORDERS.CustomerID ='C0003';` Copy this query, run it and post your comments with the error/success.

Comment: @shahkalpesh That's exactly what I have right now and it won't work. It gives me the same error.

Comment: @RachelleBennington: Paste your query please. Where is the cursor placed inside the query when the error shows up?

Comment: @shahkalpesh
`DELETE * FROM ORDERS
   WHERE ORDERS.OrderDate = #1/24/2008# AND ORDERS.CustomerID ='C0003';`

Right after the semicolon.

Comment: Never mind everyone! I figured it out. `DELETE ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID, *
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (((ORDERS.OrderDate)=#1/24/2008#) AND ((ORDERS.CustomerID)=3));'

Comment: Why on earth would you need to supply the column names in a `DELETE` statement. Sounds very strange (not to say stupid) to me. The SQL standard is `DELETE FROM some_table WHERE ...`

Comment: @RachelleBennington Perhaps you should post your own answer and then accept it to mark this issue as "closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID, * FROM ORDERS WHERE
(((ORDERS.OrderDate)=#1/24/2008#) AND ((ORDERS.CustomerID)=3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Access are surrounded by hash-signs #

```
WHERE (((ORDERS.OrderDate)=#2008-01-24#) AND ((ORDERS.CustomerID)="C0003"));
```

Comment: Try #01/24/2008#. Access is fussy about the data format. Even #1/24/2008#.

Comment: I've tried it every single way but for some reason it still won't work.

Comment: Remove the CustomerID term for the moment, being careful that you won't delete needed records! This will at least confirm that it is the date that is the problem.

Comment: @RachelleBennington: What is the error and where does the cursor show up when the error is presented?

Comment: Is the OrderDate actually stored as a Date/Time or a string/text?

Comment: @AndrewGibson It's stored as Date/Time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Orders.OrderDate is a date/time data type ? If not try :-

```
DELETE ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (((cdate(ORDERS.OrderDate))>#2008/01/24#));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a SELECT query, and trying each one of those criteria seperately.  If that DATE field is really a date/time, you'll need the # signs before and after.

```
SELECT ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (ORDERS.OrderDate)="#1/24/2008#";
```

---

```
SELECT ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (ORDERS.CustomerID)="C0003";
```

If either of them bomb then you can at least narrow down which piece isn't working and we can focus there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE ORDERS.OrderDate, ORDERS.CustomerID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDERS.OrderDate = #01/24/2008# AND ORDERS.CustomerID = "C0003"
```